# Custom Rotation Algorithm Needs Expandability

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, rotation

I'm working on a library for canvas, and I can't figure out how I should be doing rotations around the center of an object. Below is the function I'm using to render them currently and an example object I'm giving it.

I feel there is a better way to do the 4 `if` statements, but I can't figure out the math for it. Currently I am taking each "pixel" of the object and rotating it around the center, but I can't see room for expansion. What am I doing wrong?

```
//Rendering function
Display.prototype.renderObject = function(object, direction) {
    if (typeof object.rotation !== 'number') object.rotation = 0;
    for (x=0;x<object.bounds.x;x++) {
        for (y=0;y<object.bounds.y;y++) {
            rotation = 45;
            if (x==0 && y==0) rotation += 0;
            if (x==0 && y==1) rotation += 90;
            if (x==1 && y==0) rotation += 270;
            if (x==1 && y==1) rotation += 180;
            display.drawRect(object.color[x][y],
                (display.width/2) - (players[playerIndex].position.x * 16) + (object.position.x * 16) - (object.bounds.x * object.scale)/4 - (object.bounds.x/3 * object.scale * Math.cos((object.rotation+rotation)*(Math.PI/180))),
                (display.height/2) + (players[playerIndex].position.y * 16) - (object.position.y * 16) - (object.bounds.y * object.scale)/4 - (object.bounds.y/3 * object.scale * Math.sin((object.rotation+rotation)*(Math.PI/180))),
                object.scale, object.scale, object.rotation * (direction || 1));
        }
    }
};

// Example object
block = {
    "color": [
        ["#FFF","#CCC"], // Some colors to make
        ["#999","#666"]  // a shaded illusion
    ],
    "position": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
    },
    "bounds": {
        "x": 2, // color[0].length
        "y": 2  // color.length
    },
    "rotation": 0, // 0 to 360
    "scale": 4 // real pixels per object pixel
}

// Example usage
Display.renderObject(block);
```

- **edit** -

Maybe I need to have it calculate where each pixel's center coordinates would be, then get the distance from that to the origin of the object and the rotation each pixel would be offset at.

If `x = 0` and `y = 0`, then it's `+45` degrees with sin and `-45` degrees with cos`+45` degrees with sin. If `(object.bounds.x-1)/2` gives us the center coords for dealing with x, then `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2)+Math.pow(y,2))` gives us the radius for the color block from the center of the object. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure of what you're asking, but if it is how to rotate points around the points' center you *have* to translate all your points so that you object to rotate is centered around `origin` or point `[0, 0]` if you like.

A rotation matrix always rotates around origin so there is no way around (no pun intended).

So before you rotate your points calculate a delta value that you apply before the rotation, rotate and then reverse the delta and apply again to get the object back with its offset relative to origin.

So first step is to calculate the delta to find out how much you need to translate the points to get them into center.

For a rectangle it is easy: it is its x and y position plus half of its width and height:

```
 deltaX = x + width * 0.5;
 deltaY = y + height * 0.5;
```

This value you then need to subtract to the points. How you apply this delta is up to you: you can do it in advance with each point or inject it directly into the formula.

Then rotate and when done you simply apply add the delta value to each point again.

Here is a shorter version of a rotation matrix based on [my article here](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/12/canvas-transformation-matrix-explained/):

```
var a = rotation * Math.PI / 180;   /// calculate angle once
x -= deltaX;                        /// apply pre-translation
y -= deltaY;

/// rotate and apply post-translation
nx = x *  Math.cos(a) + y * Math.sin(a) + deltaX;
ny = y * -Math.sin(a) + x * Math.cos(a) + deltaY;
```

The `if`s you're using seem to come from code that use this for optimizations of the angles; when you use 0, 90 etc. as cos and sin would produce 1 and 0 respectively. You are however not utilizing this optimization as you could simply swap x for y etc. when these cases occurs. However, you bind then to x and y position so I am not sure what you try to achieve here..

I would suggest you just remove them as you calculate and applies sin/cos anyways - you could instead cache the sin and cos and use those for all the points:

```
var angle = rotation * Math.PI / 180;
    sin = Math.sin(angle),
    cos = Math.cos(angle),
    ...calc deltas here...

...enter loop here, then for each point:...
x -= deltaX;
y -= deltaY;
nx = x *  cos + y * sin + deltaX;
ny = y * -sin + x * cos + deltaY;
```

Now the cost is lower for each point and your calculations will perform faster.

Hope this helps.